# JQuery: Assign Select Box Value to Input Field

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I want to assign a value from a select box to an input field (read only)...

How can i auto fill this input field when an item is selected from select box???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('select[name=cars]').change(function()
{
   $('input[name=selected-cars]').val($(this).find('option:selected').html()) // text
   $('input[name=selected-cars]').val($(this).val()) // value
})
```

Comment: sorry, but where to put name of select box and id of input field..

the name of select box is cars, and name of input field is selected-cars..

Answer (score 7):

Simple ,Use "select" event and fill the text box

try this, [Demo -Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/PbjLV/)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$("YourSelectBoxIDOrClass").live("change", function() {
var SelectedValue=$("YourSelectBoxIDOrClass option:selected").text();
 $('#YourTextBoxID').val(SelectedValue).attr('readOnly', 'true');

});
```

I am using jQuery 1.4 so i use `live` .As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. so if you want Use .on().For details:
http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$('#selectoption ').change(function(){
    $("input[type='text']").val($("#selectoption option:selected").val());
});
```

You can replace here(input[type='text']) with specific input field...